# How can I get the last record of a JSON file using json server in Angular?

Tags: json, angular, post, json-server

I have a JSON file and I am doing post requests and then get requests. I want to get the last record in every get requests after every post request. For example:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "json-server",
    "author": "typicode"
  },
  {
    "report": "1",
    "park": "1",
    "use": "7",
    "group": "60",
    "privateplin": "30",
    "privateplus": "30",
    "first": "30",
    "second": "30",
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "report": "1",
    "park": "1",
    "use": "9",
    "group": "60",
    "privateplin": "30",
    "privateplus": "30",
    "first": "30",
    "second": "30",
    "id": 3
  },
  {
    "report": "1",
    "park": "2",
    "use": "9",
    "group": "60",
    "privateplin": "30",
    "privateplus": "30",
    "first": "30",
    "second": "30",
    "id": 4
  },
]
```

I want to get the record with id 4, but after next post request I want to get the record with id 5 etc.

```
public getJSON(): Observable<any> {

    
     return this.httpclient.get("http://localhost:3000/posts/4").pipe(
        catchError(this.errorHandler));

                     

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
counter:number;

constructor(){
     this.counter=0;
}

public getJSON(): Observable<any> {

    this.counter=this.counter+1;
     return this.httpclient.get("http://localhost:3000/posts/"+this.counter).pipe(
        catchError(this.errorHandler));

 }
```

Or you can save counter in compont, and as paramter send counter to this mathod.

```
 public getJSON(counter): Observable<any>
```

Whene you create post request, you need save your ID.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have a variable to store the current `id` of the record in JSON file.
Then after each `POST` request, you can increment or assign a new id to that variable.

To get results based on your `currentId` you will need to iterate over the JSON data that's returned from there server:

e.g:

```js
currentId = 1;

this.getJSON.subscribe((response)=>{
  if(response) {
    response.forEach((item)=>{
      if(item.id===currentId) {
       //do your operations with the selected Item
      }
  });
});

public function yourPostRequest(){

// increment or assign currentId on success
currentId++;

}
```

If you are having static data from the `getJson` then I will suggest storing that on a variable and iterating over it instead of fetching it everytime:

```js
currentId = 1;
jsonData = [];

constructor(){

this.getJSON();

}

this.getJSON.subscribe((response)=>{
  if(response) {
    this.jsonData = response;
    this.updateCurrentId();
  });
});

public function updateCurrentId(){
   this.jsonData.forEach((item)=>{
      if(item.id===currentId) {
       //do your operations with the selected Item
      }
}

public function yourPostRequest(){

// increment or assign currentId on success
currentId++;
this.updateCurrentId();
}
```